# why should the functor be placed inside the brackets while passing to thread costructor?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, syntax, most-vexing-parse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class DisplayThread
{
public:
    void operator()()     
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            std::cout<<"Display Thread Executing"<<std::endl;
    }
};
 
int main()  
{
   //line 1:
    std::thread threadObj( (DisplayThread()) );
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        std::cout<<"Display From Main Thread "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Waiting For Thread to complete"<<std::endl;
    threadObj.join();
    std::cout<<"Exiting from Main Thread"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In line 1: if i use like "threadObj(DisplayThread())", It gives an
error saying no class type.

Could someone tell me why functor while passing to thread constructor has to be inside"()" braces?

Comment: `std::thread threadObj(testObj());` calls the `DisplayThread::operator()()`. I think you want the thread to call it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations... of sorts: You have fallen victim to the C++ phenomenon known as the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): Basically, a tendency of the compiler to interpret your statements as function declarations. You are not at fault - it's the result of ambiguity in the language which happens to be resolved in a somewhat unintuitive way.

The error you [get](https://godbolt.org/z/xbnKP3) when you remove the parentheses around `DisplayThread()` is:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:20:15: error: request for member 'join' in 'threadObj', which is of 
non-class type 'std::thread(DisplayThread (*)())'
   20 |     threadObj.join();
      |               ^~~~
```

The compiler thinks `threadObj` is a function, which takes a function pointer and returns an `std::thread`!

This is [resolved](https://godbolt.org/z/xEhGaf) if you use curly-braces for no-argument construction, like so:

```
std::thread threadObj{ DisplayThread{} };
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Was not aware of this phenomenon. Learnt a new thing today.

Comment: @StraightCirle: Of course you weren't aware of it, that's why it's [vexing](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vexing) to everyone at first...